# Read Microsoft Project file (.mpp) with R?

Tags: r, ms-project

I want to read a Microsoft Project file (.mpp extension) in to R.

Loading the file as either tabular data (like a data.frame) or an object (like a list) would be fine. I'm planning to do some data manipulation and visualization within the context of a shiny app and want to let users load their .mpp files directly if possible.

I've found various ways to convert .mpp to other formats outside of R. Clicking 'save as' in MS Project is a bit of a pain, but works well enough. There are other useful import tools in other languages (including Python) and various standalone apps and web tools. The only thing I can find in R is [this example](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/msproject-odbc-r.rst) requiring a paid service.

I suppose I could use Python for data loading in Shiny, but it seems like there has to be a better way ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution, but you could follow the same route as the MPXJ Ruby gem uses:

https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/master/src.ruby/mpxj/lib/mpxj/reader.rb#L24

Here we're executing some java code in a shell which uses the MPXJ jar to consume a schedule file and dump the contents as JSON. In this case the gem then consumes the JSON and puts a nice Ruby interface around it to make it easy to access the underlying attributes. You don't need to go as far as that providing you can consume JSON from from R code you can probably just grab the attributes you need straight from the JSON.